# "Rejoin favorite rooms" button does not come back after leaving all rooms

Tags: bug, chat, favorite-rooms

If I am in multiple rooms, and I leave all of them except the current room, then the "rejoin favorite rooms" button ...

[image]

... does not return, and I am just left with an empty space:

[image]

Rather than that I think that it should look like this again:

[image]

So that I don't have to refresh the page if I want that button back.

Comment: Still occurs, came here to report the same thing. It's actually more generic than this, it doesn't only happen when you join your favorite rooms then leave them, it happens when you join *any* rooms (favorite or not) then leave them all. I'm going to edit this into a more generic bug report.

Answer (score -2):

But if you leave it intentionally after rejoining the favorites rooms, why show you "rejoin" again, if it looks like currently you don't want to be in the room you've just left?

In a real case, you wouldn't leave the room only to come back to it immediately.

(guess the system doesn't think so, but in the reality, the behavior is logical)

Comment: Well, I think that if you have left all of the favorite rooms there should be an option to rejoin again so that you are not forced to refresh because you are met with a dead end.

Comment: It's not really connected to that, it happens when you leave all other rooms regardless of whether the rooms you were in were your favorites or not. You can join another *non*-favorite room, then leave it, and the button still won't reappear.